# How to handle database exceptions in Django?

Tags: python, django, database, exception

I want to known the best way to handle database exceptions and display messages back to the user. I have been looking at `messages.add_message` in my views using a try.

For example:

The following error `(1062, "Duplicate entry '123321' for key 'PRIMARY'")`. Display back to the user friendly message: `"Error uploading CSV Duplicate entries"`

1. Is the the recommended way?
2. Are there any good tutorials on error handling (i.e. blog posts) that you would recommend as a good approach?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`Database Exceptions` are [documented](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/exceptions/#database-exceptions), 
check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11293459/630877) to see an example of how to use them.

If you are encountering this error while [processing a form](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/#working-with-forms) you should probably handle the exception when validating your form. So in case an exception is raised you [redisplay the form](http://www.djangofoo.com/61/show-form-errors-non-fiel-errors) with the appropriate error message.

Answer (score 0):

In [Django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/exceptions/#database-exceptions), these exceptions below are introduced as database exceptions and in [PEP 249](https://peps.python.org/pep-0249/#exceptions), what causes these exceptions below are explained. For example, [OperationalError](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/exceptions/#django.db.OperationalError) is caused by [lost update and write skew conditions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27826714/lost-update-vs-write-skew#answer-73847878), statement timeout, unexpected disconnection and so on:

- Error
- InterfaceError
- DatabaseError
- DataError
- OperationalError
- IntegrityError
- InternalError
- ProgrammingError
- NotSupportedError

In my opinion, using [DatabaseError](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/exceptions/#django.db.DatabaseError) should be the easiest way to handle all database exceptions.

The below is the example of **the view `test`** with **DatabaseError**:

```py
# "views.py"

from .models import Person
from django.db import transaction, DatabaseError
from django.http import HttpResponse

@transaction.atomic
def test(request):
    try:
        obj = Person.objects.get(id=2)
        obj.name = "David"
        obj.save()
    except DatabaseError as e:
        return HttpResponse(e)

    return HttpResponse("Success")
```