# 'Lost update' vs 'Write skew'

Tags: sql, database, transactions, lost-update, write-skew

Can somebody explain me whats exactly the difference between a
'lost update' and a 'write skew' in database transaction theory?
Can somebody give me an example?

Answer (score 15):

Informally, **lost updates** and **write skew** are ways that concurrent write transactions can interfere with each other.

**Write skew** happens when an update is made within a transaction based upon *stale data*. 
*Stale data* is a value read by a transaction that has become stale due to a subsequent committed write from a concurrent transaction.

**Lost updates** happen when a committed value written by one transaction is overwritten by a subsequent committed write from a concurrent transaction.  In fact, **lost update** is really a special case of **write skew**; where updates are applied to data that has become stale.

Consider the case where a database for a retail store maintains an *Inventory* table.  The database *does not* implement *transaction isolation*.

The *Inventory* table has a "ProductId" column and an "InStock" column that counts the number of items that are currently in stock for a particular product.  Each purchase (transaction) decrements the "InStock" value by the number of items purchased.

Imagine that the store has two electric shavers (of a specific model) in stock.

Two customers each purchase one of these shavers, simultaneously.

Each of the concurrent purchases (transactions) reads the same value (two) from the shaver's "InStock" record.  The transactions each decrement the "InStock" counter and commit the updated value (one) to the database.  After both of the concurrent transactions have committed, the counter will incorrectly indicate that the shaver is still in stock (one item remaining).

One of the **updates** was **lost**.

Suppose the database implements *snapshot Isolation* (with **lost update** detection), in this case **lost updates** don't happen.  This is because *snapshot isolation* detects when a **lost update** has occurred.  After a transaction commits data, concurrent transactions that attempt to commit writes for the same data are aborted by the database.  In our example, the process for which the transaction is aborted starts a new transaction to re-read the "InStock" column, decrement it, and commit the updated value.  Assuming no other conflicts, this attempt to update the record commits successfully and the "Instock" column contains the (correct) value zero.

[Transaction isolation is a deep topic](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/transaction-isolation-levels-dbms/).

Furthermore assume that the database records inventory history in an *InventoryHistory* table. The *InventoryHistory* table has the columns "Timestamp", "ProductId", and "InStock" (remaining *after* purchase).
By design, the update to the *InventoryHistory* table is the last operation in a purchase transaction.  After the two transactions commit, the respective *InventoryHistory* records will each reflect an "Instock" value of one -- this is incorrect, since one of the records should reflect an "Instock" value of zero.  The incorrect *InventoryHistory* record is an example of **write skew**.

In this case *snapshot isolation* did not prevent anomalous data from being written to the database, since no **updates** were **lost**.  Rather, the data written was *anomalous* because a value that was read by the transaction had become stale -- this is **write skew**.  *Snapshot isolation* does not prevent **write skew**.  To prevent **write skew**, the database must implement serializable isolation.

[Read this article](https://www.cockroachlabs.com/blog/what-write-skew-looks-like/) for a rigorous discussion of write skew, serializability and snapshot isolation.

Comment: I don't think that characterizing lost updates as a special case of write skew is fully correct. In academia these are considered seperate cases, because you can meaningfully say that a database system prevents lost updates trough snapshot isolation, but not write skew.



As stated here: https://jepsen.io/consistency/models/snapshot-isolation

Comment: Looking back on it, I was just a bit confused because I had read that snapshot isolation allows write skews, but not lost updates.

Some clarification for a future reader: write skew involves concurrent transactions writing to disjoint sets of fields. Lost updates involve concurrent transactions writing to overlapping sets of variables.

Comment: Tracking multiversion serialization graphs of transactions and detecting dangerous read write graphs as in serializable snapshot isolation (SSI) allows write skew to be prevented. See the paper [Serializable isolation for snapshot databases](https://dl.acm.org/doi/10.1145/1376616.1376690)

Answer (score 6):

- **Lost update** is that two transactions read the same row to update it but the first committed update is overwritten by the second committed update.
- **Write skew** is that two transactions read the same data to insert, update or delete rows but the committed data is inconsistent.

First, this is the example of **lost update** below. There is **`product` table** with **`id`**, **`name`** and **`stock`** as shown below.

#### `product` table:

| id | name | stock |
| --- | --- | --- |
| **1** | **Apple** | **10** |
| **2** | **Orange** | **20** |

**These steps below** shows **lost update**. *The stocks of the products decrease when customers buy the products:

| Flow | Transaction 1 (T1) | Transaction 2 (T2) | Explanation |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| **Step 1** | **`BEGIN;`** |  | **T1 starts.** |
| **Step 2** |  | **`BEGIN;`** | **T2 starts.** |
| **Step 3** | **`SELECT stock FROM product WHERE id = 2;`** **20** |  | **T1 reads `20` which is updated later to `13` because a customer buys 7 oranges.** |
| **Step 4** |  | **`SELECT stock FROM product WHERE id = 2;`** **20** | **T2 reads `20` which is updated later to `16` because a customer buys 4 oranges.** |
| **Step 5** | **`UPDATE product SET stock = 13 WHERE id = 2;`** |  | **T1 updates `20` to `13`.** |
| **Step 6** | **`COMMIT;`** |  | **T1 commits.** |
| **Step 7** |  | **`UPDATE product SET stock = 16 WHERE id = 2;`** | **T2 updates `13` to `16` after T1 commits.** |
| **Step 8** |  | **`COMMIT;`** | **T2 commits.** #### *Lost update occurs. |

Second, this is the example of **write skew**. There is **`doctor` table** with **`id`**, **`name`** and **`on_call`** as shown below.

#### `doctor` table:

| id | name | on_call |
| --- | --- | --- |
| **1** | **John** | **True** |
| **2** | **Lisa** | **True** |

**These steps below** shows **write skew**. *At least one doctor must be on call but finally, no doctor is on call:

| Flow | John's Transaction (JT) | Lisa's Transaction (LT) | Explanation |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| **Step 1** | **`BEGIN;`** |  | **JT starts.** |
| **Step 2** |  | **`BEGIN;`** | **LT starts.** |
| **Step 3** | **`SELECT count(*) FROM doctor WHERE on_call = True;`** **2** |  | **JT reads `2` so John can take a rest.** |
| **Step 4** |  | **`SELECT count(*) FROM doctor WHERE on_call = True;`** **2** | **LT reads `2` so Lisa can take a rest.** |
| **Step 5** | **`UPDATE doctor SET on_call = False WHERE id = 1;`** |  | **JT updates `True` to `False` which means John takes a rest.** |
| **Step 6** | **`COMMIT;`** |  | **JT commits.** |
| **Step 7** |  | **`UPDATE doctor SET on_call = False WHERE id = 2;`** | **LT updates `True` to `False` which means Lisa takes a rest.** |
| **Step 8** |  | **`COMMIT;`** | **LT commits.** #### John and Lisa both take a rest. #### *Write skew occurs. |

Next, this is also the example of **write skew**. There is **`event` table** with **`id`**, **`name`** and **`user`** as shown below.

#### `event` table:

| id | name | user |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | **Make Sushi** | **John** |
| 2 | **Make Sushi** | **Tom** |

**These steps below** shows **write skew**. *Only 3 users can join **the event "Make Sushi"** but finally, 4 users join it:

| Flow | Transaction (JT) | Transaction (LT) | Explanation |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| **Step 1** | **`BEGIN;`** |  | **T1 starts.** |
| **Step 2** |  | **`BEGIN;`** | **T2 starts.** |
| **Step 3** | **`SELECT count(*) FROM event WHERE name = 'Make Sushi';`** **2** |  | **T1 reads `2` so only one user can join it.** |
| **Step 4** |  | **`SELECT count(*) FROM event WHERE name = 'Make Sushi';`** **2** | **T2 reads `2` so only one user can join it.** |
| **Step 5** | **`INSERT INTO event values ('Make Sushi', 'Lisa');`** |  | **T1 inserts `Lisa` to `event` table.** |
| **Step 6** | **`COMMIT;`** |  | **T1 commits.** |
| **Step 7** |  | **`INSERT INTO event values ('Make Sushi', 'Kai');`** | **T2 inserts `Kai` to `event` table.** |
| **Step 8** |  | **`COMMIT;`** | **T2 commits.** #### 4 users join it. #### *Write skew occurs. |

These tables below are my experiment results of **lost update** and **write skew** with each isolation level in **MySQL** and **PostgreSQL**. ***`Yes`** means ***Occurs***, **`No`** means ***Doesn't occur*** and `SFU` means ***SELECT FOR UPDATE***.

**MySQL**:

| Isolation Level | Lost Update | Lost Update with SFU | Write Skew | Write Skew with SFU |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| **READ UNCOMMITTED** | **Yes** | **No** | **Yes** | **No** |
| **READ COMMITTED** | **Yes** | **No** | **Yes** | **No** |
| **REPEATABLE READ** | **Yes** | **No** | **Yes** | **No** |
| **SERIALIZABLE** | **No** | **No** | **No** | **No** |

**PostgreSQL**:

| Isolation Level | Lost Update | Lost Update with SFU | Write Skew | Write Skew with SFU |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| **READ UNCOMMITTED** | **Yes** | **No** | **Yes** | **No** |
| **READ COMMITTED** | **Yes** | **No** | **Yes** | **No** |
| **REPEATABLE READ** | **No** | **No** | **Yes** | **No** |
| **SERIALIZABLE** | **No** | **No** | **No** | **No** |