# Why use SELECT FOR UPDATE? (MySQL)

Tags: mysql, database, transactions, innodb, select-for-update

I have a question regarding what purpose we are using `SELECT FOR UDPATE`? What does it do exactly?

I have 2 tables, from that I need to select rows from table and update the same rows.

For example:

**Select Query**

```
SELECT * from  t1 WHERE city_id=2 for update
```

**Update Query**

```
UPDATE t1 SET final_balance = final_balance - 100 WHERE city_id ='2'
```

My question - Does this really lock the read operation till my update is done, or what does it exactly deal with?

My idea is nobody can read/update from/to these rows until my update finished.

Comment: Why not read the manual? http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/innodb-locking-reads.html

Comment: "*My idea is nobody can read/update from this rows*" - this is wrong. A row lock does not prevent _read_ access (e.g. a normal `select` without `for update`)

Answer (score 49, accepted):

`SELECT ... FOR UPDATE` will lock the record with a write (exclusive) lock until the transaction is completed (committed or rolled back).

To select a record and ensure that it's not modified until you update it, you can start a transaction, select the record using `SELECT ... FOR UPDATE`, do some quick processing, update the record, then commit (or roll back) the transaction.

If you use `SELECT ... FOR UPDATE` outside of a transaction (autocommit ON), then the lock will still be immediately released, so be sure to use a transaction to retain the lock.

For performance, do not keep transactions open for very long, so the update should be done immediately.

Comment: Doesn't the transaction guarantees the lock? In other words does SELECT ... FOR UPDATE makes sense only if transaction has a low isolation level ( like read_uncommit) ?

Comment: In my opinion, SELECT ... FOR UPDATE is usually applied under "read committed" isolation level.

Comment: @J.J.Beam transactions guarantee locks on an `UPDATE`, but not a `SELECT` (read). so if you do a `SELECT ...` without `FOR UPDATE` at the beginning of your transaction then use the selected row(s) information later in your transaction for an update, it's possible that another transaction updated the row(s) that you queried earlier in your transaction. Hence it is necessary to use a `SELECT ... FOR UPDATE` within a transaction if you need to use the queried rows later. Read: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-transaction-isolation-levels.html

Answer (score 15):

In **MySQL**, **`SELECT FOR UPDATE`** is used to prevent **lost update** and **write skew** (see more about these problems [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27826714/lost-update-vs-write-skew/73847878#73847878) to 'Lost update' vs 'Write skew'). Note: in MySQL, only `SERIALIZABLE` transaction isolation level prevents those problems without `SELECT FOR UPDATE` but **deadlock error** can occur even in that case, so we should use `SELECT FOR UPDATE` anyway.

Below I show lost update and write skew and how to prevent them with `SELECT FOR UPDATE` with the `REPEATABLE READ` isolation level.

First, this is the example of **lost update** below. There is **`product` table** with **`id`**, **`name`** and **`stock`** as shown below.

#### `product` table:

| id | name | stock |
| --- | --- | --- |
| **1** | **Apple** | **10** |
| **2** | **Orange** | **20** |

**These steps below** shows **lost update** without **`SELECT FOR UPDATE`** in **MySQL**. *The stocks of the products decrease when customers buy the products:

| Flow | Transaction 1 (T1) | Transaction 2 (T2) | Explanation |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| **Step 1** | **`BEGIN;`** |  | **T1 starts.** |
| **Step 2** |  | **`BEGIN;`** | **T2 starts.** |
| **Step 3** | **`SELECT stock FROM product WHERE id = 2;`** **20** |  | **T1 reads `20` which is updated later to `13` because a customer buys 7 oranges.** |
| **Step 4** |  | **`SELECT stock FROM product WHERE id = 2;`** **20** | **T2 reads `20` which is updated later to `16` because a customer buys 4 oranges.** |
| **Step 5** | **`UPDATE product SET stock = '13' WHERE id = 2;`** |  | **T1 updates `20` to `13`.** |
| **Step 6** | **`COMMIT;`** |  | **T1 commits.** |
| **Step 7** |  | **`UPDATE product SET stock = '16' WHERE id = 2;`** | **T2 updates `13` to `16` after T1 commits.** |
| **Step 8** |  | **`COMMIT;`** | **T2 commits.** #### *Lost update occurs. |

Next, **these steps below** shows how to prevent **lost update** with **`SELECT FOR UPDATE`** on **MySQL**. *The stocks of the products decrease when customers buy the products:

| Flow | Transaction 1 (T1) | Transaction 2 (T2) | Explanation |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| **Step 1** | **`BEGIN;`** |  | **T1 starts.** |
| **Step 2** |  | **`BEGIN;`** | **T2 starts.** |
| **Step 3** | **`SELECT stock FROM product WHERE id = 2 FOR UPDATE;`** **20** |  | **With "SELECT FOR UPDATE", T1 reads `20` which is updated later to `13` because a customer buys 7 oranges.** |
| **Step 4** |  | **`SELECT stock FROM product WHERE id = 2 FOR UPDATE;`** | **T2 needs to wait for T1 to commit to read `stock` with "SELECT FOR UPDATE".** |
| **Step 5** | **`UPDATE product SET stock = '13' WHERE id = 2;`** | **Waiting...** | **T1 updates `20` to `13`.** |
| **Step 6** | **`COMMIT;`** | **Waiting...** | **T1 commits.** |
| **Step 7** |  | **`SELECT stock FROM product WHERE id = 2 FOR UPDATE;`** **13** | **Now with "SELECT FOR UPDATE", T2 reads `13` which is updated later to `9` because a customer buys 4 oranges.** |
| **Step 8** |  | **`UPDATE product SET stock = '9' WHERE id = 2;`** | **T2 updates `13` to `9` after T1 commits.** |
| **Step 9** |  | **`COMMIT;`** | **T2 commits.** #### *Lost update doesn't occur. |

Second, this is the example of **write skew**. There is **`event` table** with **`name`** and **`user`** as shown below.

#### `event` table:

| name | user |
| --- | --- |
| **Make Sushi** | **John** |
| **Make Sushi** | **Tom** |

**These steps below** shows **write skew** without **`SELECT FOR UPDATE`** in **MySQL**. *Only 3 users can join **the event "Make Sushi"**:

| Flow | Transaction (JT) | Transaction (LT) | Explanation |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| **Step 1** | **`BEGIN;`** |  | **T1 starts.** |
| **Step 2** |  | **`BEGIN;`** | **T2 starts.** |
| **Step 3** | **`SELECT count(*) FROM event WHERE name = 'Make Sushi';`** **2** |  | **T1 reads `2` so only one user can join it.** |
| **Step 4** |  | **`SELECT count(*) FROM event WHERE name = 'Make Sushi';`** **2** | **T2 reads `2` so only one user can join it.** |
| **Step 5** | **`INSERT INTO event values ('Make Sushi', 'Lisa');`** |  | **T1 inserts `Lisa` to `event` table.** |
| **Step 6** | **`COMMIT;`** |  | **T1 commits.** |
| **Step 7** |  | **`INSERT INTO event values ('Make Sushi', 'Kai');`** | **T2 inserts `Kai` to `event` table.** |
| **Step 8** |  | **`COMMIT;`** | **T2 commits.** #### 4 users join it. #### *Write skew occurs. |

Next, **these steps below** shows how to prevent **write update** on **MySQL** with **`SELECT FOR UPDATE`**. *Only 3 users can join **the event "Make Sushi"**:

| Flow | Transaction (JT) | Transaction (LT) | Explanation |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| **Step 1** | **`BEGIN;`** |  | **T1 starts.** |
| **Step 2** |  | **`BEGIN;`** | **T2 starts.** |
| **Step 3** | **`SELECT count(*) FROM event WHERE name = 'Make Sushi' FOR UPDATE;`** **2** |  | **With "SELECT FOR UPDATE", T1 reads `2` so only one user can join it.** |
| **Step 4** |  | **`SELECT count(*) FROM event WHERE name = 'Make Sushi' FOR UPDATE;`** | **T2 needs to wait for T1 to commit to read `event` table with "SELECT FOR UPDATE".** |
| **Step 5** | **`INSERT INTO event values ('Make Sushi', 'Lisa');`** | **Waiting...** | **T1 inserts `Lisa` to `event` table.** |
| **Step 6** | **`COMMIT;`** | **Waiting...** | **T1 commits.** |
| **Step 7** |  | **`SELECT count(*) FROM event WHERE name = 'Make Sushi' FOR UPDATE;`** **3** | **Now with "SELECT FOR UPDATE", T2 reads `3` so no users can join it.** |
| **Step 8** |  | **`COMMIT;`** | **T2 commits.** #### 3 users join it. #### *Write skew doesn't occurs. |