# Django: How to handle exception when the database is down/cannot connect?

Tags: python, django, database, exception, redirect

We're having a problem on our django application. Occasionally, the database goes down/has too many connections, etc and Django continuously raises exceptions.

How can we catch these exceptions and redirect the user to an error page?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to show custom page for error 500 and then save the exceptions in logs, the following steps may help:

1. To view exceptions you can use logging setup from [here](https://github.com/ianalexander/ianalexander/blob/master/content/blog/getting-started-with-django-logging-in-5-minutes.html).
2. Create a new HTML file `error_500.html` in your app `templates/errors/` folder.
3. Add view function `error_500` to your app's `views.py`:

   def error_500(request):
       return render(request, 'errors/error_500.html')
4. Add routing to urls.py (either main or in your app's). For example

   from django.conf.urls import handler404, handler500
   from YOURAPP import views as yourapp_views

   handler404 = yourapp_views.error_404
   handler500 = yourapp_views.error_500

From now, in *production* mode (DEBUG=0, ALLOWED_HOSTS is set, run as WSGI etc.) , when exception occurs, Django should display contents of your error_500.html as Error 500 page. You will see more information in system logs.

Answer (score 0):

With [DatabaseError](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/exceptions/#django.db.DatabaseError)  in **`test` view** below, you will be able to handle all database exceptions then redirect users to error page when a database exception occurs:

```py
# "views.py"

from django.db import transaction, DatabaseError 
from django.shortcuts import redirect, render
from .models import Person

@transaction.atomic
def test(request):
    try:
        obj = Person.objects.get(id=2)
        obj.name = "David"
        obj.save()
    except DatabaseError as e:
        return redirect("/error-page/")

    return render(request, 'myapp/success.html')
```

*In [Django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/exceptions/#database-exceptions), you can check database exceptions and in [PEP 249](https://peps.python.org/pep-0249/#exceptions), you can check what causes the database exceptions. For example, [OperationalError](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/exceptions/#django.db.OperationalError) is caused by unexpected disconnection, statement timeout, [lost update and write skew conditions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27826714/lost-update-vs-write-skew#answer-73847878) and so on.