# Django / Python: catch MySQL IntegrityError

Tags: python, mysql, django

In Django/Python, how do I catch a specific mySQL error: 'IntegrityError':

```
try:
   cursor.execute(sql)
except IntegrityError:
    do_something
```

Not sure what I should import and from where.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

DId you try `from django.db import IntegrityError`?

Answer (score 0):

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11293380/django-catching-integrity-error-and-showing-a-customized-message-using-template) is a similar response . In summary

```
from django.db import IntegrityError
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response

try:
# code that produces error
except IntegrityError as e:
return render_to_response("template.html", {"message": e.message})
```